# pip trying to install using old version of python

Tags: pip, python-3.7

so I just uninstalled a wrong version of python 3.8 and downloaded python 3.7.4

Now I'm trying to install packages using the command pip install X and get the following error.

```
C:\Users\User>pip install cv2
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install cv2': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

clearly it is still trying to use the old version of python 3.8 even though I have uninstalled it and reinstalled pip several times.

Any idea on why its trying to look for this old path? and how can I change the default path it is using?

(btw this is just a matter of convenience because as of the moment if I use the command `python -m pip install X` it does seem to work)

Answer (score 0):

1. try command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. Delete and clear environment config and install again...